# Каким образом следует отмечать вопросы, содержащие мат в скриншотах?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги

Вчера в очереди проверок увидел ["шедевральный" вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471556/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-pytelegrambotapi), содержащий **скриншот** с кучей подросткового мата.  Это уже не первый раз, когда текст вопросов формально корректный, а скриншоты могут содержать различного рода нецензурные выражения, ругательства, оскорбления и пр.

Поставил на данном вопросе тревогу "невежливый или оскорбительный", которая была отклонена по причине *тревоги стоит использовать, только чтобы предупредить модераторов о необходимости их вмешательства*.

Вопрос, как всё-таки следует отмечать подобного рода контент?  Удаление скриншота с матом вследствие редактирования я не рассматривал, так как формально тогда полностью потерялся бы смысл вопроса.

Comment: Модераторы тоже могут ошибаться и мискликать. Прошел по ссылке, поставил тревогу. О результатах сообщу позже

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Постановка тревоги "невежливый или оскорбительный" - правильное действие для таких вопросов. Именно эту тревогу стоит выбирать в 99% случаев, если пост содержит мат.

Однако, существует два альтернативных сценария:

1. Мат\оскорбления не бросаются в глаза автоматически или обфусцированы (намеренно или случайно).
2. Предыдущая тревога была отклонена, **однако очевидно**¹, что пост содержит что-то абсолютно непотребное.

В этих случаях, стоит использовать тревогу "Требуется вмешательство модератора", где у вас будет возможность кратко описать, что именно является оскорблением и куда смотреть. Не стоит злоупотреблять использованием такой тревоги, однако, в данном конкретном случае, это оправдано.

---

¹ "Очевидность" — понятие растяжимое, однако я имею ввиду, что очевидно, что модератор не обратил внимание на **явное** нарушение, а не посчитал, что нарушения нет.